# How can I write each row to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, read.csv

I currently have code that is writing to a csv file, however, it keesp replacing the first row of the file and overwriting it instead of writing of it.

**NOTE: I have this function inside a for loop inside main().**

```
def write_csv_report(filename, region, data, current, server1, server2=False):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
        try:
            dir = os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
            
            header = ['region','old_dns_server', 'proposed_dns_server1', 'proposed_dns_server2']
            data = [region, current, server1, server2]

            with open(filename, 'a') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(header)
                writer.writerow(data)

        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
```

When I run this function in my script, it writes to the file but only one entry is added.

Is there any suggestions or solution where I can add multiple entries? I have looked at other sage questions and googled but it looks like I already have the necessary changes needed to achieve this outcome, not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What makes you think the data is being overwritten? You have the file open in append mode. The issue seems to be your if condition - it never goes in after creating the file once (with just 1 row, since your code is inserting one at a time). You can check by placing a print statement inside the `try` block

Comment: Your code structure is not good. You should not open / write header / write one row / close per call. You will end up with multiple headers and it would be very inefficient

Answer (score 1):

For `csv.writer` (and `csv.reader`),  [you need to open the file with `newline=''`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

You also write the header every time, which is a bit odd.

Here's a minimal example that does more-or-less what you want:

```py
import csv

header = ['region','old_dns_server', 'proposed_dns_server1', 'proposed_dns_server2']

data1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'quux']
data2 = ['foo1', 'bar1', 'bar1', 'quux2']

filename = 'test.csv'

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data1)

with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(data2)
```

giving:

```
region,old_dns_server,proposed_dns_server1,proposed_dns_server2
foo,bar,bar,quux
foo1,bar1,bar1,quux2
```