# What does "iterable expected, not function" mean in when outputting data to a CSV in Python when using the CSV library?

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics

I'm trying to pull data from the new V4 API of google analytics. I'm changing the script on the google analytics quick start page, so I have a CSV file being outputted with the columns that I want

Quickstart script is here:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

I'm trying to use the CSV library to write the CSV, found here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

The script is here: (I have changed the key file and view ID just for anonymity)

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import csv
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import time
import datetime
import csv
import random
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import socket
from google.colab import files

import calendar 



SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics

#from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py
def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
         'metrics': [
                      {'expression': 'ga:Users'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:screenviews'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:timeOnScreen'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:entrances'},
                     {'expression': 'ga:exits'}
                  ],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:screenName'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()

def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range:', str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)
#this gives me an output, but not in the form that I want. 
def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()





#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902380/how-can-i-write-each-row-to-a-csv-file
#https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
header = ['screenName','Users', 'pageviews', 'screenviews','sessions', 'timeOnPage','timeOnScreen','bounces','entrances','exits']
filename = 'test.csv'

analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
report = main

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(report)
```

The specific error that I'm getting is:

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-940ae7480962> in <module>()
     10     writer = csv.writer(file)
     11     writer.writerow(header)
---> 12     writer.writerow(report)
     13 
     14 if __name__ == '__main__':

Error: iterable expected, not function
```

I'm not sure if I understand what an iterable is, and I'm not sure what I can do to the script to make it run

Comment: An 'iterable' means a data type that can contain multiple elements that can be iterated over. So, a list or array for example. The error means writer.writerow is expecting a list, or array, of data. However, you are apparently passing a function instead. What is the value of 'main'? It's probably not what you expect

Comment: @Vvamp thank you, I edited the question as I had deleted the 'main' function- it was used on the original GA quickstart to print the data, and I was trying everything to fix it  (apart from the actual way of fixing it). I'm still a bit new with python so just getting a bit bogged down here.

Comment: That's okay, but so your issue is: you are setting 'report' to the function 'main'. When trying to write that to your csv, python gets confused(as it can't iterate over a function). You can still use your main function, but you'll want to call it instead and then return something from the main function. For instance: add 'return response' to the end of your main function and change 'report = main' to 'report = main()'. This way, you call the function main and store the result(which in this case is 'response') in the report variable. Not sure if that fixes it, but it should help you

Comment: Ahhh right, thank you, that makes sense. I at least have an output now, and the function is pushing the right headers, just the data inside says "response" rather then numbers so it's a separate issue now.

Comment: That is odd. Did you put the variable name in quotes in the return statement by any chance? So, did you do return "response" instead of return response ?

Comment: I changed it to  ```  header = ['screenName','Users', 'pageviews', 'screenviews','sessions', 'timeOnPage','timeOnScreen','bounces','entrances','exits']
filename = 'test.csv'

def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  return response


with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(main()) ```